# Modeling objects with multiple table relationships in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, model

I'm toying with Zend Framework and trying to use the "QuickStart" guide against a website I'm making just to see how the process would work. Forgive me if this answer is obvious, hopefully someone experienced can shed some light on this.

I have three database tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `first` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
  `last` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
  `gender` enum('M','F') default NULL,
  `birthyear` year(4) default NULL,
  `postal` varchar(16) default NULL,
  `auth_method` enum('Default','OpenID','Facebook','Disabled') NOT NULL default 'Default',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `user_password` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(16) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `user_metadata` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `signup_date` datetime default NULL,
  `signup_ip` varchar(15) default NULL,
  `last_login_date` datetime default NULL,
  `last_login_ip` varchar(15) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I want to create a User model that uses all three tables in certain situations. E.g., the metadata table is accessed if/when the meta data is needed. The user_password table is accessed only if the 'Default' auth_method is set. I'll likely be adding a profile table later on that I would like to be able to access from the user model.

What is the best way to do this with ZF and why?

Comment: Very unclear on why this is down-voted: is there a problem with this question? I couldn't find a similar question that explain this in the detail I'm looking for. Let me know if I can be more clear.

Comment: Dunno, excess of data perhaps? You could replace all that SQL with brief description of tables.

Comment: Seems that someone downvoted all new questions

Comment: @andybaird: your title is a little bit off. these are not multiple data sources, they're just multiple tables from one data source, your db. having many tables (like really loads) is a normal thing for big applications.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
class Users extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'users';
    protected $_rowClass = 'User';
    protected $_dependentTables = array ('UserMetadata', 'UserPassword');

...

class UserMetadata extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'user_metadata';
    protected $_referenceMap = array (
    'Users'=> array (
    'columns'=>'user_id',
    'refTableClass'=>'Users',
    'refColumns'=>'id'
    )
    );

...

class UserPassword extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'user_password';
    protected $_referenceMap = array (
    'Users'=> array (
    'columns'=>'user_id',
    'refTableClass'=>'Users',
    'refColumns'=>'id'
    )
    );
```

Fetching data:

```
$id = //get your user id from somewhere

$users = new Users();
$user = $users->fetchRow('id=?', $id);
if ($user->authMethod == 0)
{
    $metadata = $user->findDependentRowset('UserMetadata')->current();
}
```

or

```
$user = $users->fetchRow($users->select()
              ->where('gender=?, 'M')
              ->order('email ASC');
```

... etc.

Inserting data:

```
$newRow = $users->fetchNew();
$newRow->email = me@domain.com;
$newRow->save();
```

or

```
$users = new Users();
$data = array('email'     => 'me@domain.com',
              'firstname' => 'Me');
$users->insert($data);
```

Updating:

```
$user->email = 'me@domain.org';
$user->save();
```

Deleting a row:

```
$user->delete();
```

Using transaction:

```
$db->beginTransaction();
$db->commit();
$db->rollback();
```

etc... it's all in the [ZF Manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/)!

Comment: This makes the most sense to me - so how do you handle an insert into the users table? Logically, there should be a user_metadata row created as well. Can I handle that on the model level somehow?

Comment: The logics to create a meta-data row when creating a user-row you have to write yourself. but that's easy. if you want to do it the clean way use transactions...

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing, and it worked quite well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Basically instead of using `Zend_Db_Table` use more general `Zend_Db_Select` or `Zend_Db_Statement` to retrieve data.

BTW. You might want to access password data not directly in User model, but rather in your User auth class derived from `Zend_Auth_Adapter`.

Comment: I don't plan on accessing password data via user model, except to update it. 

Doesn't using Zend_Db_Select completely circumvent the idea of modeling user data as a single object?

Comment: It's not ORM, there's no need for 1-to-1 class-table mapping.

Comment: BTW. the 1=1 mapping would be possible if your DB was in 3NF, your problem comes from the fact, that you denormalized your DB, splitting user data into 3 tables.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell I would create a model for each table, not one model that accesses all three. I would then [define relationships](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html) between the tables.

To be honest it seems not very "DRY" to have to create a model for each table but that is what I see done repeatedly in the various examples online and it is what I have done in the handful of projects that I have created with the Zend Framework. If anyone has a better way of handling this I hope the will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the best way to do this with ZF is by using [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Just a few notes straight off the bat:

The first User table, seems more like a Person table, except for the auth method, but you could put that in the User_Password table, which you could probably rename User. The User_Metadata table seems like it could just be amalgamated with the User_Password/User table.

Now, even without those changes, you have three distinct tables, with three distinct concepts, if you model each of those separate as different classes, and then had a UserModel class as a facade of sorts to access each, it would likely make it easier.